# How to detect user activity on the keyboard

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

My task is to detect the text changes in the TextView of my app, as close to real time as possible. However, with Swype-style virtual keyboards like SwiftKey, the whole word appears at once. Is there any way to at least detect that user is doing some actions with the virtual keyboard, like moving the finger on it?

Comment: You want to check if the text change in a TextView or EditText ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Textwatcher. You will be able to see every change. This work with EditText and TextView(Even if I never tried with a TextView)

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
    }
    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

    }
```

And you juste have to add it with :

> TextView.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher)